# HTTP port exposed but not responding properly

Tags: docker, docker-machine

Running Docker 1.9.1 on OpenSuse 42.1 (can't upgrade at this time but also the same problem on Docker 1.12).

I have a Docker images that exposes a web application on port 8080. I can ssh into the container and access the application correctly from inside the container on http://localhost:8080/.

I run the container using

```
docker run -p 10000:8080 ...
```

and I would expect the web application being accessible on either

```
http://localhost:10000 or http://public-ip:10000
```

The port is open but the connection is being closed immediately.

```
sudo netstat -nap|grep LISTEN|grep -v LISTENING|grep 1000
root's password:
tcp        0      0 :::10000                :::*                    LISTEN      17375/docker-proxy
```

I can telnet to port 10000 but as said the connection is being closed immediately

```
docker --version
Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5
docker version
Client:
Version: 1.9.1
API version: 1.21
Go version: go1.4.2
Git commit: a34a1d5
Built: 
OS/Arch: linux/amd64
Server:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

docker info (1.9)
Containers: 23
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 22
Images: 198
Server Version: 1.12.6
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-8:2-1074640197-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs                                                                                                                                                                                          
 Data file: /dev/loop0                                                                                                                                                                                            
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1                                                                                                                                                                                        
 Data Space Used: 13.22 GB                                                                                                                                                                                        
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB                                                                                                                                                                                       
 Data Space Available: 94.16 GB                                                                                                                                                                                   
 Metadata Space Used: 20.58 MB                                                                                                                                                                                    
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB                                                                                                                                                                                   
 Metadata Space Available: 2.127 GB                                                                                                                                                                               
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74 GB                                                                                                                                                                           
 Udev Sync Supported: true                                                                                                                                                                                        
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false                                                                                                                                                                                  
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 WARNING: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` to specify a custom block storage device.
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.136 (2016-11-05)
Logging Driver: journald
Cgroup Driver: systemd
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: null bridge host overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: oci runc
Default Runtime: oci
Security Options: seccomp
Kernel Version: 4.11.8-200.fc25.x86_64
Operating System: Fedora 25 (Server Edition)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
Number of Docker Hooks: 2
CPUs: 6
Total Memory: 29.45 GiB
Name: dev2.zopyx.com
ID: DE7T:KEX4:UCRB:KOED:2DHE:3437:MYDS:LPQT:BBYO:SOQH:2EZL:VTYR
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Registries: docker.io (secure)


docker info (1.12)
Containers: 23
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 22
Images: 198
Server Version: 1.12.6
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-8:2-1074640197-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 13.22 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 94.16 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 20.58 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.127 GB
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 WARNING: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` to specify a custom block storage device.
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.136 (2016-11-05)
Logging Driver: journald
Cgroup Driver: systemd
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host overlay null
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc oci
Default Runtime: oci
Security Options: seccomp
Kernel Version: 4.11.8-200.fc25.x86_64
Operating System: Fedora 25 (Server Edition)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
Number of Docker Hooks: 2
CPUs: 6
Total Memory: 29.45 GiB
Name: dev2.zopyx.com
ID: DE7T:KEX4:UCRB:KOED:2DHE:3437:MYDS:LPQT:BBYO:SOQH:2EZL:VTYR
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Registries: docker.io (secure)
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Are you using any volume with the container?

Comment: No volumes involed here

Comment: Can you post `docker info` please?

Comment: Updated information with "docker info" for my 1.9 and 1.12 installation

Answer (score 0):

Solution: the webservice internally was only binding to 127.0.0.1 instead to 0.0.0.0